# what's wrong with this basic scheme function

Tags: function, scheme, lisp

I'm trying to write a scheme function that does the following (taken from SICP):

> Exercise 1.3. Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments
> and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

Here's my attempt:

```
(define (square-sum-larger a b c)
  (cond ((and (< a b) (< a c))) (+ (* b b) (* c c)))
  (cond ((and (< b c) (< b a))) (+ (* a a) (* c c)))
  (cond ((and (< c a) (< c b))) (+ (* b b) (* a a)))
)
```

When I enter this into the biwa scheme interpreter, I get the following:

```
(square-sum-larger 4 5 6)
16
```

Since `4` is less than `5` and `6`, shouldn't the first condition be evaluated, meaning that the sum of the squares of `5` and `6` should be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define (square-sum-larger a b c)
  (cond ((and (< a b) (< a c))) (+ (* b b) (* c c))) ;; this is thrown away
  (cond ((and (< b c) (< b a))) (+ (* a a) (* c c))) ;; this is thrown away
  (cond ((and (< c a) (< c b))) (+ (* b b) (* a a)))
)
```

Only the last of the three `cond` does anything useful; the previous `cond` expressions do not have any side effect, since they perform only calculations, and their value is not used. The are dead code which a Scheme compiler can eliminate entirely.

You probably wanted to combine all of the clauses into a single cond:

```
(define (square-sum-larger a b c)
  (cond ((and (< a b) (< a c))) (+ (* b b) (* c c))
        ((and (< b c) (< b a))) (+ (* a a) (* c c))
        ((and (< c a) (< c b))) (+ (* b b) (* a a))))
```

Comment: To me, what you write is obvious, but what is *not* obvious to me is why the result in the OP's code is `16`. As you write, the first two `cond` expressions are just NOPs, they are dead code, and the third `cond` expression has only one branch which is not taken. So, actually, *nothing* is being evaluated at all in the OP's case, which in my mind should mean that the result is `'()`. Where does the `16` come from?

Comment: Ah, I found the answer in R7RS 4.2.1: "If all <test>s evaluate to `#f`, and there is no else clause, then the result of the conditional expression is unspecified […]" Interestingly, the Racket documentation says that the program aborts with an error if all tests evaluate to `#f`, but the actual result in Racket still seems to be `16` and no error. There is a high possibility, though, that I have a version mismatch between documentation and interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

```scm
(define (square-sum-larger a b c)
  (cond ((and (< a b) (< a c))) (+ (* b b) (* c c)))
  (cond ((and (< b c) (< b a))) (+ (* a a) (* c c)))
  (cond ((and (< c a) (< c b))) (+ (* b b) (* a a)))
)
```

Is basically this in JS:

```js
function squareSumLarge(a, b, c) {
   // not tail position , dead code regardless if the test is truthy
   if (a < b && a < c) {
     b * b + c * c;
   }
   // not tail position , dead code regardless if the test is truthy
   if (b < c && b < a) {
     a * a + c * c;
   }
   if (c < a && c < b0 {
     // return because cond is in tail position 
     return b * b + a * a; 
   } else {
     // if the last cond term didn't hit it returns an implementation chosen value
     return undefined;        
   } 
}
```

Know that this pattern:

```js
if (test1) {
  return expression1;
} elseif (test2) {
  return expression2;
} else {
  return expression3;
}
```

is done like this with `cond` when the `cond` is in tail position:

```scm
(cond 
  (test1 expression1)
  (test2 expression2)
  (else expression3))
```